# Triggers misfire in Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

Is there any way by which we can resume triggers in Quartz once system is back online?

We have some scheduled trigger(with frequency interval 6 hours), Sometime our system went down and it skips the execution of those triggers.

Can anyone suggest if its possible using Quartz scheduler to resume trigger those missed during downtime.

Comment: Have you tried using persistent job stores? which job store are you using?

Comment: We are using org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.

Answer (score 4):

You should include "**MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION**" with your trigger, while defining it. The below example shows **MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW**

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger().
    startAt(DateUtils.addSeconds(new Date(), -10)).
    withSchedule(
        simpleSchedule().
            withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow()  //MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW
        ).
    build();
```

For a detailed explanation : [see this](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html)